# How to call a web service from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have on scenario which I have to call a web service from SQL Server. Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: There is - create a [CLR stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx) that does this. However be prepared that this will occasionally crash the entire SQL server. We've been through this, on a slow network when the moon is in the right phase, something unexplainable happens inside the .NET framework and it abnormally shuts down, taking the server with it and leaving a puzzling error message in the log.

Comment: You can also use `sp_OACreate` methods but I don't think these are supported anymore and they are even less reliable than CLR

Comment: But in Visual studio 2012, we cannot use Webservice directly. We have no option for that.

Comment: You can use a web service an any visual studio, at least from 2008 up. Right-click the project and select Add service reference (or web reference).

Comment: Yes GSerg, you are right. But we cannot use web service in SQL Server Database Projects.

Comment: @user484458 Which is a hint for you that you shouldn't do it in the first place. But if you really want it, create an ordinary class library project and install the dll manually with `create assembly`.

Comment: @GSerg,I created CRL project and added the webservice sucessfully.But I'm unable to fine the xlmserializer.dll file.Even the GENERATE SERIALIZATION ASSEMBLY is set to auto. even I tried by setting it to ON. but no xlmserializer.dll file is created.
because of this I was unable to create assembly of xlmserializer.dll  and it's giving the error when I execute the procedure in SQL
"Cannot load dynamically generated serialization assembly.In some hosting environments assembly load functionality is restricted, consider using pre-generated serializer.Please see inner exception for more information."

Answer (score 0):

As GSerg mentioned in comments, this is something you can do within a SQL CLR procedure.  This link will walk you through a proof of concept scenario, but the principles are there.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/11/25/how-to-consume-a-web-service-from-within-sql-server-using-sql-clr.aspx

Depending on what you need to do with it, you can also build an SSIS package.  It has an out-of-the-box task for web services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx

Comment: But in Visual studio 2012, we cannot use Webservice directly. We have no option for that.

Comment: You can add a service reference in your project. You also have the option to create a proxy service (local copy) and add that as a reference in your project.

Comment: This post has an example with the UPS API using VS2012, SQL CLR and a proxy service. http://www.sanjaykumar.us/index.php/creating-clr-stored-procedure-to-call-external-web-services/

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SQL Server Data Tools for Business Inteligence](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) (SQL2012+) or Business Inteligence Development Studio (SQL2008[R2]) to create an `Integration Services` project including [Web Service Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx):

[image]